# Returning value in underscore each loop does not stop the function

Tags: javascript, return, underscore.js, each

I noticed a strange behaviour, at least one I don't understand, while returning value inside an underscore each loop. My code is the following, it basically test wether or not an element is already present in an array based on its id, like this :

```
var elements = [{id: "1", name : "foo"},{id : "3", name: "bar"}];

element_exists = function(key, val){
    _.each(elements,function(element){
        console.log(element[key], val);
        if(element[key] == val){
            console.log("element exists");
                return true;
        }
   });
   return false;
};

console.log("true : ", element_exists("id", "1"));
console.log("false : ", element_exists("id", "2"));
```

I get the following log in the console :

```
1 1
element exists
3 1
true : false
1 2
3 2
false : false
```

My question is why does the function does not return true for the first element ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@ltbesh You are getting it wrong!
The function **does** return the value & stop.
It only continues executing the iterator function for the remaining elements in the input.

You are confusing loop statements with `_.each` method.

The second parameter to the `_.each` method is an iterator function. It is basically a function that is executed for every element of the array. So, if you write a `return` statement in your iterator function, it only terminates that particular function call. The function continues to be called for the remaining elements in the array.

#### Update

---

#### UnderscoreJS solution

What you need to use instead is `_.find` or `_.some` underscore methods. (Well, now that its 2020 it is high time we abandon using underscore and lodash to get functionality that ES6 provides out-of-the-box). But, since the question is about underscoreJS, I'll first provide a solution using underscore.

```js
var elements = [{id: "1", name : "foo"},{id : "3", name: "bar"}];

element_exists = function(key, val){
    return _.find(elements,function(element){
        return element[key] === val;
   });
};

console.log("true : ", element_exists("id", "1"));
console.log("false : ", element_exists("id", "2"));
```

```html
<script src="https://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

#### ES6 based solution

Now, just to show how succinct it is to accomplish the same functionality in ES6 without any external library, here's the ES6 version:

```js
var elements = [{id: "1", name : "foo"},{id : "3", name: "bar"}];

element_exists = (key, val) => (
    elements.find(element => element[key] === val)
)

console.log("true : ", element_exists("id", "1"));
console.log("false : ", element_exists("id", "2"));
```

PS: If you only want to check if the element exists and don't want it to be returned by your `element_exists` method, switch from using `find` to `some`.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you're always returning false from the function.

Rewrite to this if you want to keep on using the `each()` function.

```
var elements = [{id: "1", name : "foo"},{id : "3", name: "bar"}];

element_exists = function(key, val){
  var someFlag = false;  
  _.each(elements, function(element){
        console.log(element[key] +" - "+ val);
        if(element[key] == val){
            console.log("element exists");
            someFlag = true;
        }
   });
   return someFlag;
};

console.log("should be true : " + element_exists("id", "1"));
console.log("should be false : " +element_exists("id", "2"));
```

Comment: Thx, that's what I ended up doing but what I don't understand is why does the function doesn't stop when it encounter a return statement, I expected it to just return the value and stop doing other things.

Comment: No, that would be the `break` keyword that does that. I've always thought that using a break is of poor design myself and try not to use it that much.

Comment: @ltbesh You are getting it wrong!
The function does return the value & stop.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but the accepted answer did not provide a solution so:

Underscore suggests to use the function `_.find`, which iterates over a list of values and returns the first one that passes a truth test, and `undefined` otherwise.

This way you can break out of the loop.
However, since the return value is the actual element instead of a boolean, you may, upon calling your function, add a wrapper to return `true` if the function returned a defined value.

`_.some` might also apply better to your use case.

Sources:

http://underscorejs.org/#each

http://underscorejs.org/#find

http://underscorejs.org/#some